# Redirect to openDocument from editDocument in Xpages?

Tags: xpages

If a user enters a URL with a action=editDocument, I want to be able to redirect them to the same URL but with action=openDocument.

I assume that I would use the beforePageLoad event?

How could I prevent them from going to the action=editDocument and redirect them to a action=openDocument url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will redirect back to the same page if the parameter action is "editDocument" (and thereby prevent the user from editing the document):

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:
        if (param.get("action")=="editDocument") {
            context.redirectToPage(view.getPageName())
        }
    }]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

**Update:** As Mark points out in his answer, the above answer will not preserve a documentId parameter if included. You can check if the documentId parameter is included and then do a proper redirect using that parameter:

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:
        if (param.get("action")=="editDocument") {
            context.redirectToPage(view.getPageName() + "?action=openDocument&documentId=" + param.get("documentId")
        }
    }]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have editDocument, you'll probably have a docID in the request, in which case `view.getRequestUrl()` is more useful than `view.getpageName()`

Comment: Good point, Mark. Yes, my answer will not preserve a docID if included. I will update my answer.